# Is there a way to have certain object in a class not be re-assignable by certain code?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows Service which looks at a list of dlls (in a settings file), loads them all in, and starts a specific method in each of the dlls on its own thread. Each of these dlls must inherit from a specific class (Module class) in order to be used by this service, and part of that class is an MPI object, basically an instance of a class that lets the dll methods call methods to interact directly with the service. How it goes is:

> 1. Service loads dll
> 2. Uses reflection to check that there is a class that inherits the Module class
> 3. Creates a new instance of that Module inherited class
> 4. Creates a new instance of the MPI class. This has identifying information about which Module is using it
> 5. Assigns the newly created MPI object to the new Module class
> 6. Starts the main Module thread

The base module class itself is its own dll (so that both the service and the external dll can work with it). What I want to do is have the service be able to assign an MPI object, which special values, to the new Module class, but I don't want that class to be able to 
change the MPI object assignment, or any of the values inside of it. ReadOnly for the inherited class, but assignable from the other. I assume I can't do this the way I have things set up how, what changes would I have to do to make this possible. Is it even possible?

Pretty much MPI is like an API for the main hosting service. It handles a few centralized things, like error logging. When the service loads up a new Module it assigns it an ID. When that Module calls `MPI.ErrorLog(someStuff)` then MPI, which has references to the main service memory, and thus can access the actual error writer, will write that Module ID # had this error at this time. I want ID to be private to the the class that inherits Module, but not to the the main service, so that ID can be set by it. Don't say private variables with a constructor that sets everything, because I don't want the Module to be able to create a new MPI object itself and be able to change these things around.

Comment: drop the explanation, show the code! Most people on SO have no patience to read a wall of post

Comment: @Aniket I only have half completed code that does what I describe above. I was in the process of making it when I realized I don't know how to do what I wanted to do, so there isn't really any code to show, just an idea. I tried to make a mock up, but I didn't feel it really described my problem.

Comment: Can you modify the methods in the dlls? If yes, you could make a method in each dll, for example `RegisterMpi(IMyMpi mpi)`. In the `IMyMpi` interface you could have only those methods that don't change  your MPI object - like `LogError()`. Then the dlls can call this object's method from inside to log or otherwise interact with the main service.

Comment: @DanielGabriel Right now I can modify the dlls since I'm the one who makes them. The idea was, in the future, others would be adding dlls to it and I wanted easier ways for them to just drop some code in with things still being somewhat secure.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to modify the access to a single object for different contexts/users. For example, the 'base' knows about the get and set accessors, while the 'module' only knows about the get accessors. I can imagine two options here - access modifiers, and interfaces.

Firstly, the [`internal` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c5ka91b.aspx) makes a member visible to only files in the same assembly.

```
public class Mpi
{
    private int id;

    int Id
    {
        public get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        internal set
        {
            this.id = value;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Thus your 'module' will assume that this is a get-only property, while your 'base' will be able to both get and set.

Your second option would be to have an interface which defines only the get accessors.

```
public interface IMpi
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Mpi : IMpi
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

In this model, the 'base' class uses the `Mpi` object and the 'module' class uses an `IMpi` object. They are the same instance, but again the module doesn't know that the `Id` property has a set method.

Comment: I question if your second idea would work, since the Module class isn't defined in the service, so I wouldn't be able to make some part of it available to the service, but completely restrict that from the inheriting class... But I think using internal may work, if I rework things. The issue is that the service and MDI are two separate assemblies, but the logical thing to do would be to move most of the functional code to the MDI assembly, turn the service into a glorified bootstrapper for MDI, and keep all of these secret values as internal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
var modules = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll").AsParallel()
              from type in Assembly.LoadFile(file).GetTypes().AsParallel()
              where !type.IsInterface && typeof(Module).IsAssignableFrom(type)
              select (Module)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Then you declare your Module base class:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Mpi Mpi { get; set; } // to inherit you must implement getter (you don't need it) and setter (what you're asking about)

    public abstract void Main(); // to inherit you must implement too
}
```

And use:

```
Mpi mpi = new Mpi();
foreach (Module m in modules)
{
     m.Mpi = mpi;
     m.Main();
}
```

---

Another solution. If base class haы a parameterless constructor it will be called always. Inside you can assign a variable writable by base class only:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    protected Module()
    {
        this.Mpi = new Mpi();
    }

    protected Mpi Mpi { get; private set; } // getter is visible to children, setter only for class itself
}
```

Comment: This is actually all of the code I had worked out before I came here to ask this. The issue is that I don't want a module to be able to reassign their MPI variable to a new one. The idea is, I wanted to be able to create and set MPI from the caller, restrict the module from doing that, all while MPI was in a separate assembly from both of those. Looks like I have something of a solution involving internal, though.

Comment: @cost: But where can child class re-assign the variable of Mpi?

Comment: If the child class can call methods that are within MPI, then it would be able to reassign the MPI object itself with another `MPI = new MPI();`

Comment: Yes, but then how do I assign it from the main thread that starts the module? MPI still needs to be assignable from the start

Comment: @cost: Outside of modules creation loop? Setter can be `internal` also `static`. Modules/children outside main assembly will have no access to it, only getter.

Comment: That was the problem, the MPI class is in a separate DLL/assembly from both the creating loop and the module itself, meaning I couldn't use internal. But I'm moving things around now so that I can use internal

Comment: @cost: As far as I understand, you don't need internal modifiers in MPI class/assembly but in ModuleBase class/assembly. So module creation loop class had access to instantiate/assign MPI. Right?

Comment: I have three assemblies. The main service, MPI/Base Module, and the Module Child. The main service creates an instance of the module child and creates a new MPI object for it with an identifier. The child needs to be able to work with MPI without being able to create a new instance or change its identifier. MPI was originally in a separate assembly because I wanted both the service and the child to have access to the same assembly for communication purposes. If MPI was in the service I wouldn't have a way to import it into my child DLL.

Comment: @cost: I would have internal constructor in MPI class. Also an idea - replace MPI concrete type with interface and make its implementation not visible to children (i.e. internal too). Then children will be able only set MPI reference to null (using reflection maybe). But will cannot re-assign it because they will have no class/type to instantiate.

Comment: @cost: Misread your comment. 3 assemblies: service (loop); mpi class, base class; children. Then you can't have internal setter. I see now.

Comment: @cost: So you need make Mpi in Assembly2 assignable from Assembly1 (service) but not from Assembly3 (children), correct?

Comment: @cost: So from what I see, base class in Assembly2 instantiates MPI and exposes it to children in read-only mode to children in Assembly3. Service in Assembly1 instantiates base class/modules.

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted. But it looks like I'm not able to do this from the way I have things set up with three separate assemblies, so I need to do some rearranging.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I could also accomplish what I want using `InternalsVisibleTo`

Comment: @cost: Sounds good but remember this is not a really elegant and clear design/solution.

Comment: Do you have a better idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24472/discussion-between-abatishchev-and-cost)

Comment: @cost: I wish I had. InternalsVisibleTo usually used in unit tests as merely acceptable solution, it's always to avoid that for clearer design, read not by you but another guy. Or even by you but 1-2-3 years later. That's what I mean. I will think about better solution though.